# How to implement MediumEditor gem within SimpleForm in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, medium-editor

I want to add [MediumEditor](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor) to a simple form field where users are able to write texts. There is a [gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/medium-editor-rails/2.2.0) for rails but I don't know how to implement it within a simple form.. How the f.input field should look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the MediumEditor docs, this is how to use it:

> You can now instantiate a new MediumEditor object:
>
> ```
> <script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>
> ```
>
> The above code will transform all the elements with the `.editable` class  into HTML5 editable contents and add the medium editor toolbar to them.

You need to reference the input element by its `id` or `class`. If you are using `form_for`, the id of the input element that it generates will follow the format `"OBJECT_ATTRIBUTE"`, where `OBJECT` is the name of the object for which you are building the form, and `ATTRIBUTE` is the name of the attribute which the form field corresponds to.

So if your form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
```

the resulting html element will look like this:

```
  <textarea id="article_body" name="article[body]" cols="60" rows="12"></textarea>
```

So you'd have to pass the `id` `"article_body"` to the MediumEditor constructor, like this:

```
 <script>var editor = new MediumEditor('#article_body');</script>
```

You can also choose any arbitrary `id` or `class` for your input element passing it as an option to the form builder:

```
<%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12", id: "my-medium-editor-text-area" %>
```

---

**Edit:**  I just noticed you're using Simple Form. If you wanted to pass a custom `id` using simple form it would have look something like this:

```
  <%= f.input :article, input_html: { id: "my-medium-editor-text-area" } %>
```